# UISwitch inside of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiswitch

I have a table view with a custom cell (`UISwitch` on every cell of the tableview).

I have set my cell like this:

```
switchView = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200.0f, 5.0f, 75.0f, 30.0f)];
cell.accessoryView = switchView;
[switchView setOn:NO animated:NO];
[switchView addTarget:self action:@selector(favorite:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[cell addSubview:switchView];
```

And the action that is called by the user when he changes the `UISwitch` is:

```
-(IBAction)favorite:(id)sender 
{
    indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell*)[sender superview]];
    NSMutableArray *favoriteList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSString *favoriteItem = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].textLabel.text;
    NSLog(favoriteItem);

    if ([switchView isOn]) 
    {
        [favoriteList addObject:favoriteItem];

        NSUserDefaults *favoriteDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [favoriteDefaults setObject:favoriteList forKey:@"MyFavorites"];
        NSLog(@"%@", favoriteList);
    }
    else
    {
        [favoriteList removeObject:favoriteItem];

        NSUserDefaults *favoriteDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [favoriteDefaults setObject:favoriteList forKey:@"MyFavorites"];
        NSLog(@"%@", favoriteList);
    }
}
```

**The problem is:**
When testing the app, just the last item (cell) of the table view works properly.

For the others, the debugger returns that the state of the `UISwitch` is always "OFF".

What is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of immediate reactions:

1. In `(IBAction)favorite:(id)sender` you are not grabbing the switchView for the cell in question, but rather just using what was used by the last reference of that class ivar. Likewise, in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you appear to be setting (and repeatedly resetting) this same, single `switchView` ivar. Probably shouldn't be an ivar at all. You could make `switchView` a local variable of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. You could also make it a local variable of `favorite`. But most importantly, `favorite` should setting it as `UISwitch *switchView = sender`.
2. I presume you want to save all of your favorites to user defaults. Your current `(IBAction)favorite:(id)sender` will recreate favoriteList each time, and it will have either one item in it or no items in it, but certainly discarding any other favorites you may have selected in the past.
3. A minor point, but if you set the accessory cell, you don't need to also add the switchView to the subview.

So, I'd suggest modifying `cellForRowAtIndexPath` as follows:

```
NSString *title = [_favorites objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; // clearly, you'll get the text however you're getting your text now ... I'm just storing in array
cell.textLabel.text = title;

BOOL isFav = [self isFavorite:title]; // go to user defaults and find out if it's there or not

UISwitch *switchView = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200.0f, 5.0f, 75.0f, 30.0f)];
[switchView setOn:isFav animated:NO];
[switchView addTarget:self action:@selector(toggleFavoriteSwitch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
cell.accessoryView = switchView;
```

This uses `isFavorite`:

```
- (BOOL)isFavorite:(NSString *)title
{
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSArray *listOfFavorites = [userDefaults objectForKey:kMyFavsKey];

    if (listOfFavorites)
        return [listOfFavorites containsObject:title];

    return NO;
}
```

Then, obviously, you need to define your `toggleFavoriteSwitch` (previously called `favorite`) method:

```
- (IBAction)toggleFavoriteSwitch:(UISwitch *)switchView
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[switchView superview];

    [self updateFavoriteInUserDefaultsFor:cell.textLabel.text withValue:[switchView isOn]];
}
```

And this is updating user defaults as follows:

```
- (void)updateFavoriteInUserDefaultsFor:(NSString *)title withValue:(BOOL)isOn
{
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSArray *oldFavorites = [userDefaults objectForKey:kMyFavsKey];

    NSMutableArray *newFavorites;

    if (!oldFavorites)
        newFavorites = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    else
        newFavorites = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:oldFavorites];

    if (isOn)
        [newFavorites addObject:title];
    else
        [newFavorites removeObject:title];

    [userDefaults setObject:newFavorites forKey:kMyFavsKey];

    [userDefaults synchronize];
}
```

Hopefully this remedies your issue.